# Vuejs list doesn't reRender while push and change item

Tags: vue.js

I want push some data to **items**, and use another list **names** to reference some data.

```
  <div v-for="item in items" track-by='$index'>
    {{item.id}} - {{names[item.id].value}}
  </div>
```

When modify **names**, list didn't reRender as expect.

This is a demo for my problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/sumy/ep0d28j7/

When click **Add ME**, I want all the same key with same value. But ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Due to the limitation of ES5, Vue.js **cannot detect property addition or deletion**. Since Vue.js performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the `data` object in order for Vue.js to convert it and make it reactive.

http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Use global `Vue.set(object, key, value)` to make **names** reactive.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem when updating a data array, but I have found a way to force the Vue instance to re-render manually using `vm.$forceUpdate()` here is the [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate) on the Vue official documentation.

```
// vue instance
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        array: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    },
    methods: {
        handleClick: function(i) {
            // update your data array
            this.array[i] = "some string";

            // force the instance to be re-rendered
            vm.$forceUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will cause the UI to rerender, but will not make the new item in the array reactive. i.e. the UI will not update automatically if the new element changes. In this example with a simple string that may be acceptable, but if you are inserting objects into the array you will want them to be reactive.

Answer (score 1):

Editing an array item using the square brackets notation won't be picked up by the reactivity system

Comment: Actually it's not, and I explained you why. If you use `push` you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

I found that whatever is being listed with the v-for needs to be wrapped with some type of list, e.g.

Does NOT rerender when 'pages' is updated:

```
  <v-ons-card v-for="(page, index) of pages" v-bind:key="index"
      @click="push(page.component, page.label)"
  >
     <div class="title">{{ page.label }}</div>
     <div class="content">{{ page.desc }}</div>
  </v-ons-card>
```

DOES update when 'pages' is updated:

```
<ul>
      <v-ons-card v-for="(page, index) of pages" v-bind:key="index"
          @click="push(page.component, page.label)"
      >
         <div class="title">{{ page.label }}</div>
         <div class="content">{{ page.desc }}</div>
      </v-ons-card>
</ul>
```

Comment: I Can't see any difference between these two snippets!

Comment: You need to wrap the 'v-for' in a list tag, e.g. '<ul> ... </ul>'